# Toggle all elements with a given css class

Tags: javascript, toggle, prototype, each, scriptaculous

I'm trying to toggle multiple elements with a given css-class all at the same time with a single checkbox. This looks like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle_class('.subdivision_wraps');" />
```

JS:

```
function toggle_class(cssClass) {
  $$(cssClass).each(function(s){
    new Effect.toggle(s, 'blind', { duration: 0.3 });
  });
}
```

Should work, right? Wrong.. Only the first div gets toggled. Strangely enough if I use BlindDown everything works just the way I want it to (all the divs get blinded down simultaneously).

Am I doing something wrong? I know I could use BlindDown and BlindUp, but I'd rather solve this toggle-problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be some strange problem with `Effect.toggle`. If you give the `div` elements `id` values, your code works: http://jsbin.com/ifeqek/1 If you don't, you get the effect you're seeing: http://jsbin.com/ifeqek/3

So I'd probably update `toggle_class` to:

```
function toggle_class(cssClass) {
  $$(cssClass).each(function(s){
    s.identify(); // <======== The new bit, assign an id if there isn't already one
    new Effect.toggle(s, 'blind', { duration: 0.3 });
  });
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ifeqek/4) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ifeqek/4/edit)

Comment: Seems like it needs to wait for the previous effect to finish before it runs the next: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/Cpr82/

Comment: @JamesAllardice: That also seems to work, but it doesn't need the delay if they have `id` values (something I *totally* stumbled upon). Very odd.

Comment: It's to do with the fact that effects applied to elements without an `id` are added to a queue called "global". When there is an `id`, its added to a queue with that `id` as its name (and separate queues can run simultaneously). But that doesn't really explain why the delay is required... that's the point of adding them to a queue!

Comment: Simple and quick fix, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!